# How to optimize a bard's ability with a bow in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

Specifically, the question would be for a halfling bard whose main combat role I want to have is ranged with the bow—as no one else seems to be taking any interest there.  More interested in accuracy than sheer damage, but damage would be nice, too.  So far the character has as relevant stats: 18 Dex, Point Blank Shot, and Deadly Aim.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Someone has actually done an entire [How-to guide](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/extras/community-creations/treatmonks-lab/test2) for pathfinder bards, with an entire section on bow specialists. I would suggest giving it a read-through, and then if you're still having problems check back here for potential solutions.

Comment: Cool!  I'll definitely take a look at that.

Comment: Wow, thanks alot.  That answered this question and a number of others I hadn't even thought of.

Comment: Treantmonk has very good guides :) ALthough in that case I'm a bit confused by how/why the Archer part is almost totally independent from the bard part

Comment: Is there a place to find more of those?

Comment: @Mikalichov I'm curious about this too. Something I've missed that gives Bards a particular synergy with the Bow ?

Comment: @Nigralbus There isn't, really. However, the build will allow the bard to still be a valuable member of the party in combat. Any class could use the build, it's basically just a generic-archer build with a limited number of feats.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link for a complete build guide for a optimized pathfinder bard archer http://www.optibuilds.com/pathfinder-optimized-bard-build-archer-god

Comment: You might summarize the useful points and put them in the answer.. Also, they specify halfling and this build says human. Doesn't make it useless, but that's where your interpretation/translation in the answer would come in handy.